# Why does this script fail because it doesn't like the column name?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

It doesn't like the word *release* as a column name.

```
 CREATE TABLE external_db (

      external_db_id          INT not null,
      db_name                     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      release                    VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
      status                      ENUM ('KNOWNXREF','KNOWN','XREF','PRED','ORTH', 'PSEUDO') not null,

      PRIMARY KEY( external_db_id ) 

    );
```

[image: Error in MySQLWorkbench]

I changed the field name to releaseX and the error went away.

This script came from https://github.com/Ensembl/ensembl/blob/release/91/sql/table.sql, which is supposed to be mySQL. Is this a versioning issue in MySQL or can I decorate the word *release* in the script so it can be used as a column name?

I am using MySQL 5.7 and MySQLWorkbench 6.3.

I know *release* is a bad name for a column but I didn't write the script.

Comment: Because "release" is a keyword and part of sql commands. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-6-detailed-R

Comment: The field is called "db_release" in the file you linked on Github. Just saying.

Comment: @rlanvin You're right. Good catch. I have no idea how I changed that. Thanks!

Comment: @nicomp No worries. Feel free to mark my answer as accepted while you're at it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Release is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

To use it as a column name, you can escape it with backticks like this:

```
`release`
```